# What does this message mean in R?

Tags: r

After creating a large 3d array, I have tried to open this array. Then I have received this message:

```
function (object, contr, how.many, ...) 
{
    if (!nlevels(object)) 
        stop("object not interpretable as a factor")
    if (!missing(contr) && is.name(Xcontr <- substitute(contr))) 
        contr <- switch(as.character(Xcontr), poly = "contr.poly", 
            helmert = "contr.helmert", sum = "contr.sum", treatment = "contr.treatment", 
            SAS = "contr.SAS", contr)
    if (missing(contr)) {
        oc <- getOption("contrasts")
        contr <- if (length(oc) < 2L) 
            if (is.ordered(object)) 
                contr.poly
            else contr.treatment
        else oc[1 + is.ordered(object)]
    }
    if (missing(how.many) && missing(...)) 
        contrasts(object) <- contr
    else {
        if (is.character(contr)) 
            contr <- get(contr, mode = "function")
        if (is.function(contr)) 
            contr <- contr(nlevels(object), ...)
        contrasts(object, how.many) <- contr
    }
    object
}
<bytecode: 0x0000016e171a6878>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

What does it mean? Why can't i see the values of my array?

Comment: That is the code for the function  `C` ; I'm guessing you have typed the wring object name

Comment: Have you named your array `C`? If so, when you type `C` R might be printing the function with that name, not the array, like @user20650 says.

Comment: "C#alaga". However that was the problem, thanks